# Advantages of using Bluemix's SQL Database service vs ClearDB MySQL on Bluemix App

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I have a bluemix app that is currently setup with the ClearDB MySQL 3rd party bluemix service through PHP. The service works well, however I noticed that there is a limit of 5mb of space for the free version (you can upgrade from there). I recently looked into Bluemix's own SQL Database service and it offers up to 100mb of space free per instance running on Bluemix. What are the advantages of the ClearDB service? To me it seems that Bluemix's own service would be a lot more cost effective. What are the considerations?

Thank you,

--

Answer (score 1):

They are based on different RDBMS: [ClearDB](https://www.cleardb.com/developers) is based on MySQL while [SQL Database](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SQLDB/index.html) is powered by IBM DB2, so that should be the first thing to consider when choosing between them. For example if you are deploying an existing application that works on MySQL you may want to use the same DBMS.
 If the underlying technology is not important (or you don't have any constraint on it) please note that, as you can see in the [Bluemix Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/), ClearDB is a Third Party while SQL Database is an IBM service. This means that the latter is developed by IBM and you can get a quicker support when experiencing issues with your database.

Comment: Thank you for the response! What kinds of issues can arise when running an existing MySQL app on IBM DB2? I have many tables and stored procedures setup in my MySQL app's current database, would all of this work on IBM DB2?